# edit two separate progress bars in html

Tags: javascript, html

That's my problem: I need to update two separates progbars with their own width but the And bar take the Or percentage and the Or one remains empty. I'm not so good with HTML and Js but I noticed that changing div class=progress-bar the And one works but the Or one doesn't. How can I fill every bar with its percentage?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>skills</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="page-top">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
                        <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800"></h1>   
                    </div>
                    
<!--SKILLS--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">

<!--AND--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<body>
<div class="m-4">
    <h4 class="small font-weight-bold">AND</h4>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="min-width: 0px;"></div> <!-- Progress bar HTML -->
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script>
        const and=["And_1","And_2","And_3","And_4","And_5","And_6","And_7"];
        const myand=["And_1","And_2"];
        var la=and.length;
        var lm=myand.length;
        var mywid=0;
        for(let i=0; i<la; i++){
            for(let j=0; j<lm; j++){
                if(and[i]==myand[j]){
                    mywid++;
                }
            }
        }
        var perc=(99/la)*mywid;
        perc=Math.round((perc + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100

        var bar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
        function makeProgress(){
            bar.style.width = `${perc}` + "%";
            bar.innerText = `${perc}` + "%";
        }
        makeProgress();
    </script>
</div>
</body>
<!--OR--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<body>
<div class="m-4">
    <h4 class="small font-weight-bold">OR</h4>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="min-width: 0px;"></div> <!-- Progress bar HTML -->
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script>
        const or=["Or_1","Or_2","Or_3","Or_4","Or_5"];
        const myor=["Or_1"];
        var lo=or.length;
        var lmo=myor.length;
        var orwid=0;
        for(let i=0; i<lo; i++){
            for(let j=0; j<lmo; j++){
                if(or[i]==myor[j]){
                    orwid++;
                }
            }
        }
        var orperc=(99/la)*orwid;
        orperc=Math.round((orperc + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100

        var orBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
        function makeProgress(){
            orBar.style.width = `${orperc}` + "%";
            orBar.innerText = `${orperc}` + "%";
        }
        makeProgress();
    </script>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the same elements width twice using `document.querySelector(".progress-bar")`

instead you should give each progress bar an unique ID and set the width for them separately

In HTML:

```
<div class="progress-bar"  id="and-bar" style="min-width: 0px;"></div>
```

Query selector in Javascript:

```
var andBar = document.querySelector("#and-bar");
```